# If real numbers $x$ and $y$ fit the equality $\frac{2x+i}{y+i}=\frac{1+i\sin\alpha}{1+i\sin3\alpha}$, what does $\frac{x}{y}$ equal?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If real numbers $x$ and $y$ fit the equality $\dfrac{2x+i}{y+i} = \dfrac{1+i\sin\alpha}{1+i\sin3\alpha}$, what does $\dfrac{x}{y}$ equal?

If I tackle it the standard way, the expression gets more complicated than it should be. Given the place of this question in the test,  it should have a relatively simple solution.

Much appreciated.

Comment: `If I tackle it the standard way` ...you get $(2x+i)(1+i\sin3\alpha)=(y+i)(1+i\sin\alpha)\,$, then identifying the real and imaginary parts gives the equations for $x,y\,$ (and, in particular, equating the imaginary parts gives the $x/y$ ratio directly). It doesn't get much simpler than that.

Comment: @John Doe There is no trig here at at all. You could have used $p,q$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly simpler solution.
$$(2x+i)(1+i \sin{3\alpha}) = (y+i) (1+i\sin{\alpha})$$
Now let us equate the imaginary terms.
$$i(1+2x\sin{3\alpha})=i(1+y\sin{\alpha})$$
$$2x\sin{3\alpha}=y\sin{\alpha}$$
$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{2\sin{3\alpha}}{\sin{\alpha}}$$
$$\frac{y}{x}=2(2\cos^2{\alpha} + \cos^2{\alpha} - \sin^2{\alpha})$$
$$\frac{y}{x}=2(1 + 2\cos^2{\alpha} - 2\sin^2{\alpha})$$
We know that $\cos{2x}=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}$, so we get.
$$\frac{y}{x}=2 + 4\cos{2\alpha}$$

Comment: (the problem was looking for $\frac{y}{x}$, my bad)

Why cannot I simplify $2\frac{sin3\alpha}{sin\alpha}$ to $-2-4cos2\alpha$?

Comment: Thanks for the simplification idea, however, I am fairly sure that you got the sign wrong. Check your trig identities, as that is probably where the error came in.

Comment: Well, the supposed answer is the second expression, but I also get a mistake in signs. I guess the answer is wrong?

Comment: I'll show a little more of the process so you can see how it simplifies. Is $-2-4cos2\alpha$ the given solution?

Comment: Yeah. I guess it is some sort of mistake.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \dfrac{2x+i}{y+i}= \dfrac{-i^2+i\sin{\alpha}}{-i^2+i\sin{3\alpha}}=
\dfrac{\sin{\alpha}-i}{\sin{3\alpha}-i}= \dfrac{2x+\sin \alpha  }{y+\sin{3\alpha} }$$

where we added numerators and denominators separately

Cross multiply and equate real/imaginary parts

$$ y+ \sin{3\alpha}= 2 x + \sin{\alpha} $$

$$ 2x \sin{3\alpha}= y  \sin{\alpha} $$

First equation is not useful as it gives a linear relation.But quotient relation in second equation

$$ \dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{\sin{\alpha}}{2\sin{3\alpha}} $$

gives the needed result.